# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Programmierparadigma und Programmierstil?

Tags: difference

Ein **[Programmierstil](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmierstil)** ist laut Wikipedia " ... in der Programmierung das Erstellen von Quellcode nach bestimmten vorgegebenen Regeln."

Ein **[Programmierparadigma](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmierparadigma)** ist "ein fundamentaler Programmierstil."

Was genau unterscheidet einen fundamentalen Programmierstil von einem "nicht fundamentalen"? Und ist das der einzige Unterschied zwischen den beiden Begriffen?

Comment: Ich stimme dafür, die Frage als off-topic zu schließen. Es geht nicht um Sprache, sondern um fachliche Konzepte, die in den verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikeln ausführlich erläutert werden.

Comment: Es läuft auf die Frage hinaus, was der Unterschied zwischen Stil und Paradigma ist. Je nach Kontext kann beides vieles sein, auch in Bezug aufs Programmieren, etwa solch Äußerlichkeiten wie Einrückungen in Bezug auf Programmierstil (Tabs vs. Blanks, 8er, 4er oder 2er-Schritte, ...) über Modularisierung zu Fragen ob funktional oder objektorientiert usw. Man kann Stil auch so verstehen, dass es die individuelle Note ist, die übrig bleibt, wenn man alle Konventionen, die sich in Style-Guides fassen lassen, abgezogen hat. Paradigmen kann man auch weiter oder enger gefasst betrachten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ein Programmierstil ist der Stil, den der Code eines Programmierers hat.
Dieser kann z. B. durch einen Styleguide für ein Projekt oder Unternehmen festgelegt werden.

Ein Programmierparadigma ist das Prinzip, wie eine Programmiersprache "funktioniert". Wie werden Daten repräsentiert, gibt es Objekte, Vererbung etc.? Folgt alles einem Fluss von oben nach unten, oder passiert alles gleichzeitig.

Comment: Ich halte die Beschreibung von "Programmierparadigma" für nicht 100% korrekt.Ein Programmierparadigma ist für mich die grundsätzliche Herangehensweise an eine Problematik, die Antwort auf die Frage: "Wie wird das Problem beschrieben?"

Comment: Ich kann zu dem Thema folgenden Text empfehlen: "The Paradigms of Programming" von Rober W. Floyd
https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359140
Hierbei handelt es sich meines Wissens um den ersten Text, der das Wort Paradigma in das Themengebiet der Programmierung eingeführt hat.